# Pentaho Data Integration MongoDB Input speed very slow

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I need to extract data from MongoDB and put into database, the MongoDB is a replica set with 2 secondary, and I read the MongoDB data from secondary.
I setup a simple transformation (MongoDB Input to Dummy step) to test the speed, but the MongoDB read speed is usually around 200 row/s.
I think that is too slow. 
Does anyone can share your experience, what is usual speed for MongoDB Input step and how to optimize that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i haven't worked on with mongodb lately but i may suggest to check a few things

1. are you running from local machine or remote server if yes when you run the transformation can you check the network speed as you may be sending data on network which may be slow.
   we usually configure a cart server on run the transformation on the database server to improve the performance.
2. check the commit size you may need to change it as per the stream you are working,usually increasing it helps improve.

see if below may help you https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0L0/0Y0/090/020#OptimizeDS